# SharePoint 2010 Save Site as Template fails on deleted content

Tags: site-template

Quick points

- This is NOT a publishing site
- Both the SIte Collection and site recycle bins are cleared.
- The browser history has been cleared and the browser closed and reopened.
- It's a client side for which I do not have access to the ULS logs.

History - how I got here
My client requires a new site template that populates the new sites with standard lists and libraries.  I created a blank site and then populated it with some content to demonstrate process flow.  After the demo, I deleted the imported content and now I'm trying to save the site as a template to the Solutions Gallery, however, I am getting an error stating that the server had difficulty accessing the content which was previously deleted.  As stated, the recycle bins have been cleared.
[image: ErrorDialog]